# UITextField strange behaviour for blank checking

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, notnull

I've a UITextField say txtTitle. I want to check for not blank of that field at the time of inserting data into database.

For that I written

```
if(![txtTitle.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
   //Save
}
```

But where I am shocked is its not working! I did these type of checking before and its working properly. But not with this case. So that I checking it using following,

```
if(txtTitle.text!=NULL)
{
   //Save
}
```

It's working properly.

Now here I am confusing about this. I used to print NSLog(@"%@",txtTitle.text) without inputting anything into it. Its printed (null).

Someone please justify the difference between two IF conditions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check for the length property of the string instead, using

```
if([txtTitle.text length] > 0){
// Save
}
```

I think the difference is between a completely uninitialized string and a string that has been initialized, but is simply empty.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

@Hemang
As you have mentioned that NSLog gives you (null)..you have to compare like

```
[txtTitle.text isEqualToString:@"(null)"]
```

other wise use

```
if([txtTitle.text length] > 0)
{

}
```